# Dynamic mod_rewrite for MVC site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some issues with a mod_rewrite for a MVC site I am building.

First off let me state that I am trying to capture everything after the .com in a sub directory format since the number of arguments passed in can be of varying numbers.

for instance:

```
www.domain.com/view1/param1/param2
www.domain.com/view1/param1/param2/param3
www.domain.com/view2/param1
```

views will be rather static but there will be a lot of them so I would rather not have a rule for each view.

since these can be varied greatly I want to take the URI string /viewname/params/etc and split it out into an array delimited by the / then set the view of the MVC and execute whatever actions the params call for.

What I have tried so far...

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NS]
```

**PHP**

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
die(print_r($uri)); // debug
list( $view, $params ) = explode( '/', $uri, 2 );
$params = explode( '/', $uri );
```

this is giving me a 404 error, the access logs don't show it being sent to index.php either.

**Access.log**

```
[19/Jun/2014:22:31:08 +0000] "GET /tester/p1/p3 HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0"
```

any help with my mod_rewrite woes is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your Apache config allow directory override via .htaccess?

Comment: Good Call - I enabled the override on in the apache2.conf then found that I had forgot to enable the rewrite module. now after a "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and a restart of apache it is working. Thanks for a kick in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to allow override in apache2.conf and enable the rewrite module.